# Personalizacion de woocommerce-checkout-review-order

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hola el siguiente codigo se usa para que cuando un cliente pide un presupuesto , y antes de que le de finalizar el carrito  se vea el precio.
He personalizado el caclulo del producto añadiendole el costo de envio/desplazamiento como precio final . Dicho de otro modo , el precio inicial  + envio = precio del producto.

He estado escribiendo este codigo en el archivo de review-order.php

```
 <?php 
     
      $ship = WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();
      $price =  $cart_item['data']->get_price();
      
   if (empty($ship)) {($subtotal_1='Sin datos');}else {($subtotal_1=$price + $ship);}?>
        <td class="product-total">
        <?php echo esc_html_e( $subtotal_1);?>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Con este codigo , el precio del producto que si en un principio costaba 50 € y el costo de envio es 20 € , el cliente ve solo 70 € y el costo de envio no se ve.
Pero no he sabido darle el formato de euro en subtotal_1.

Answer (score -1):

La solucion que he encontrado es la siguiente:

```
<?php 
     
      $ship = WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();
      $price = $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price();
      
     
      if (empty($ship)) {($subtotal_1='Sin datos');}else {($subtotal_1=$price + $ship);}?>
            <td class="product-total">
            <?php echo wc_price( $subtotal_1);?>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
```

Con este codigo si no coloca ninguna direccion aparece 0 €.
Espero poder corregirlo de la forma en que si no coloca ninguna direccion aparezca el texto sin datos.
Aqui esta el codigo en el que si el envio esta vacio , se oculta la fila del total del carrito:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>
    <?php if ((!empty($ship))  ) : ?>
        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total','woocommerce' ); ?> </th> 
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php else : ?>
     <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total','woocommerce' ); ?> </th> 
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

De todas formas , el formulario en el que se hace el pedido no le permitira enviarlo sin la direccion de envio. Este codigo funciona correctamente al menos en la pagina web.

Un saludo

Comment: Has puesto la respuesta en tu pregunta y luego un comentario en la respuesta... te recomiendo leer [tour] y [help] si quieres entender cómo funciona SO, y por qué tus "post" van a recibir votos negativos y/o acabar cerrados. Una respuesta debe ser siempre una respuesta, y si quieres responder a tu propia pregunta, lo haces con una respuesta y no editando la pregunta para que "incluya" la respuesta... eso no es correcto. La pones en esta sección (RESPUESTAS) y la marcas como aceptada. Preferiblemente explicando un poco cómo funciona, no poniendo solo una línea de código. Documéntala.

Comment: Creo que he corregido el post , gracias por tu comentario.